# PythonのBokehで表示したグラフのtooltipsの数値表示にeが含まれないようにする方法

Tags: python, bokeh

Bokehで表示したグラフの右側にカーソルを当てて表示されるtooltipsの数値表示にeが含まれてしまう。
このeが表示されないようにして、元のdataeに定義されているような数値が表示されるようにしたい。
どなたかご教示していただけると嬉しいです。

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool, CustomJSHover
from bokeh.palettes import d3

datae = [[ 0.  ,  0.12,  0.12,  0.3 ,  0.  , -0.09,  0.1 ,  0.08,  0.06, 0.06,  0.04,  0.03,  0.01,  0.  ,
          -0.01,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.01, 0.  ],[ 0.  ,  0.06,  0.18,  0.14,  0.05, -0.6 ,  0.25,  0.18,  0.12,
         0.08,  0.05,  0.06,  0.  ,  0.04,  0.04, -0.04,  0.05,  0.02,
         0.01],[0.  , 0.29, 0.12, 0.16, 0.05, 0.2 , 0.19, 0.26, 0.19, 0.34, 0.22,
        0.19, 0.11, 0.09, 0.08, 0.05, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02],[ 0.  ,  0.6 ,  0.5 ,  0.33,  0.5 , -0.2 ,  0.19,  0.3 ,  0.3 ,
         0.26,  0.12,  0.04,  0.03,  0.04,  0.08,  0.02,  0.03,  0.06,
         0.07],[0.  , 0.36, 0.36, 0.24, 0.03, 0.06, 0.18, 0.28, 0.16, 0.14, 0.13,
        0.15, 0.07, 0.07, 0.06, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04],[ 0.  ,  0.16,  0.3 ,  0.13,  0.09, -0.55,  0.21,  0.2 ,  0.19,
         0.14,  0.07,  0.36,  0.04,  0.14,  0.04,  0.02,  0.02,  0.03,
         0.02],[0.  , 0.21, 0.26, 0.1 , 0.05, 0.24, 0.15, 0.08, 0.12, 0.12, 0.11,
        0.11, 0.08, 0.06, 0.23, 0.06, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02],[0.  , 0.4 , 0.17, 0.25, 0.27, 0.5 , 0.08, 0.25, 0.14, 0.23, 0.2 ,
        0.17, 0.08, 0.05, 0.09, 0.06, 0.06, 0.13, 0.04]]

g = [ 'T9', 'T14',  'S5', 'S10', 'S15', 'S22', 'S25', 'S30', 'S35', 'S40',
     'S45', 'S50', 'S55', 'S60',  'H2',  'H7', 'H12', 'H17', 'H22']
cities = ['Kyoto', 'Kobe', 'Sapporo', 'Kawasaki', 'Fukuoka', 'Hiroshima', 'Sendai', 'Saitama'] 
colors = d3["Category10"][8]

x_custom = CustomJSHover(code=f'''
    const g = {g}
    return "" + g[special_vars.segment_index]
''')
p = figure(x_range=g, toolbar_location='right', tools=[HoverTool(formatters={'@x': x_custom})],
           sizing_mode='stretch_width',max_width=700, max_height=250,
           tooltips="In @x{custom} the population increase rate of @cities is $y",
           title='The Population Transition of Japanese City',
           x_axis_label='Year in Japanese Calender', y_axis_label='Populationa Increase Rate',
           width=800, height=350)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[g]*len(datae), y=datae, color=colors, cities=cities))
p.multi_line(xs='x', ys='y', line_color='color', legend_field='cities', source=source)

p.legend.location = 'center'
p.legend.title = 'The Name of City'
p.legend.title_text_font_style = 'bold'
p.legend.title_text_font_size = '15px'
p.add_layout(p.legend[0], 'right')

show(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

29行目の`tooltips`フォーマット指定時に`y{0.00}`などの有効桁数を指定してください。

```
# 変更前
tooltips="In @x{custom} the population increase rate of @cities is $y",
# 変更後
tooltips="In @x{custom} the population increase rate of @cities is $y{0.00}",
```

**参考資料**

- [Is there a way to format the float number displayed in Hover tooltips?](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-format-the-float-number-displayed-in-hover-tooltips/810)
- [Formatting tooltip fields](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#formatting-tooltip-fields)

Comment: ありがとうございます！！無事解決しました！！！